Mockito.mock(...) does not work inside an Arquillian integration test anymore
We're upgrading from Java 8 to 21 and since we run Arquillian with a remote Wildfly for integration testing, but also have some mocking inside those test classes to avoid to execute some annoying code, we ran into the problem Mockito.mock(..) will throw an exception now. I actually found a solution (link below) that should work, because it's basically the same problem, but for some reason it won't work for us. The only differences are we still run Junit 4 and the solution uses a managed Wildfly for Arquillian.
the solution: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/3304
the exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:85)
    at deployment.testarchive.war/jdk.proxy41/jdk.proxy41.$Proxy549.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:78)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:275)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:236)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:82)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2104)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:2019)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//at.felder.FERPS.EJB.Session.Transport.TransportGBOTest.testCalcMaxPArtsPerATPM(TransportGBOTest.java:5150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8$1.invokeMethod(Arquillian.java:319)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker$1.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:18)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ContainerTestExecuter.execute(ContainerTestExecuter.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:139)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:15)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$8.evaluate(Arquillian.java:326)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:198)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:344)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:48)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:209)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:273)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.on(BeforeLifecycleEventExecuter.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:159)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:267)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:160)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:344)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:48)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:171)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:109)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:61)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:139)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:117)
    at deployment.testarchive.war//org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.19.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.7.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)



the WAR for the Arquillian
@ArquillianSuiteDeployment
public class Deployments {
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive deploy(){
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class,"testarchive.war")
                .addPackages(true,"at.felder")
                .addPackages(true,"info.margreiter")
                .addPackages(true,"io.jsonwebtoken")
                .addPackages(true,"com.caucho")
                .addPackages(true,"com.cedarsoftware")
                .addPackages(true,"org.bson")
                .addPackages(true,"com.mongodb")
                .addPackages(true,"org.mockito")
                .addPackages(true,"net.bytebuddy")
                .addPackages(true,"org.objenesis")
                .addPackages(true,"org.apache")
                .addPackages(true,"com.rabbitmq")
                .addPackages(true,"com.jcraft")
                .addAsWebInfResource(new File(
                    "src/test/resources/jboss-deployment-structure.xml"))
                .addAsResource("META-INF/beans.xml", "META-INF/beans.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(new StringAsset("Dependencies: jdk.unsupported\n"
                    /*required by Mockito */), "MANIFEST.MF")
               .addAsResource("org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/providers.xml");
    }

Not sure what I should provide more to be honest. But as soon as I remove the @RunWith(Arquillian.class) from the test classes the Mockito.mock(..) will run perfectly fine.
but then the Integration tests in the same class will ofc stop to work.
I tried this solution:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/3304
didn't work while it seems to be the actual same problem.

This looks related to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFARQ-161 which appeared to be a Mockitio issue.

we were still using Junit4 and updating to Junit5 resolved the issue with that solution, so yeah you're right.
